# Use the methods of a class in a table of superclass (Java)

Tags: java, class

I'm working on a java project and I have two class (for this topic, not in the project) : the class "Objet" and the class "Cle extends Objet" with the method "getNumero()" only in Cle. In my main, I wrote this code :

```
Objet[] objets = Scenario.objets;
for (int i=0;i<objets.length;i++)
{
    if(objets[i].getClass() == modele.Cle.class 
    && objets[i].getNumero() == salle.getPorte(direction).getNumero()){}
}
```

The problem is in the second part of the "if", the class Objet hasn't a method "getNumero()", so I check if the Objet is a Cle, but java doesn't understand that if my first part of the "if" is true, the second part is possible. Can someone say if it's possible to extract a Cle from objets, and how ?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to find a different name than "Objet" for your class. This only differs by one letter from the built-in class "Object" and can cause a lot of confusion for both yourself and for people trying to answer you questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit cast, the common idiom is:

```
if (objets[i] instanceof Cle) {
   Cle aCle = (Cle) objets[i];
   aCle.getNumero(); // works
} else {
   ... // fail?
}
```

Looking further and depending on the concrete situation you could add `getNumero()` as an abstract method to `Objet`, instead of casting. If you cannot do that, maybe you could look into Generics to enable your supplier of `Objet` instance to provide `Cle` instances. That again depends on the concrete scenario.